# Path syntax to perform operations on a MySQL JSON object with an empty key

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

Given the following JSON object used in MySQL 5.7 or later:

```
{"": 1}
```

What is the valid path syntax to extract the value from the JSON object with an empty string key?

```
select JSON_EXTRACT('{"":1}', '$.""');
```

The above SQL is the best of my understanding on how to setup correct the path syntax. However, the SQL yields the following error: `Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 4.`

Any help in understanding the correct path syntax to operate on such an object would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be up against a bug.
Might require an upgrade to MySQL 5.8

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79643